# Best method for storing & retrieving (plaintext) passwords

Tags: android

For an app I am working on, I need to be able to get a plaintext password. E.g.

1. User submits password to the app. This needs to be stored.
2. The app needs to be able to access this password at a later stage (for submission to a Web service without oauth and outside of my control)

What is the best method for saving and retrieving these passwords.

Any linked tutorials etc. will be helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use secure SharedPreferences. Link: [secure-preferences](https://github.com/scottyab/secure-preferences)

> Android Shared preference wrapper than encrypts the values of Shared Preferences. It's not bullet proof security but rather a quick win for incrementally making your android app more secure.

Comment: Seems like the perfect solution. Thanks.

Comment: You may want to update your answer to include the relevant parts or an example from the link provided. See [How do I write a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @JosephGarrone I'm new to this community. I will try better next time. Thanks for the link though :)